# Validate DTO and get Error Message

Tags: c#, validation

I am working on a Web API2 application, need to validate the DTOs sent by the client conditionally. I am using the attribute based validation currently.
The design I have is to have an `IDtoValidator` interface which has an `IsValid()` method to validate data.
I need to provide the error message as well in a user readable format, which is present in the interface itself so that each class implementing the interface can put in their own error messages.

Here are my classes:

```
public interface IDtoValidator
{
    bool IsValid();
}

public class FormResponseDto : BaseResponseDto, IDtoValidator
{

     public bool IsValid()
     { ... some logic to validate the model...}
}
```

My idea of validating in the action method: 
Action Method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethod(FormResponseDto dto)
    {
         if(dto.IsValid())
            return BadRequest(dto.GetErrorMessage());
    }
```

Please suggest any clean design for this.
The problem is that in the `isValid()` method i need to set the errorMessage, which is another property of the interface. which only needs to be privately set, this cannot be done in an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a Getter in your Interface like

`String GetError()`

or

`List<String> GetErrors()`

In the 2nd prototype, you may want to return an immutable collection\list so that Error(s) cannot be added into the list externally.